# How to find value's item in sortable with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a *sortable* where it was created with loaded from JSON files.
Now I want to delete an item.

I receive from a textarea the element name that I have to cancel.
I save in a variable `namdel`.
With a for loop I am going to compare this variable with the name of the sortable.

The HTML code of the *sortable*:

```
<div id="sortparam">

<ul style="" class="ui-sortable" id="sortable">
    <li style="" id="1" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Singular sensation</li>
    <li style="" id="2" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Beady little eyes</li>
    <li style="" id="3" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Little birds </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

The problem is how to read the items because if I read with:

```
var contapara=1;
var l = document.getElementById(contapara).innerHTML;
alert(l);
```

The program write in alert window:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Little birds
```

I want only `Little birds`.

Comment: Can't you give your `<li>` elements meaningful names or `data-`attributes when parsing the JSON file instead of mucking with the rendered HTML?

Comment: Also: please use English identifiers in code samples.

Comment: @millimoose: Does it really matter what the variable is named?

Comment: I've edited your question title, I hope it rephrases your request better.

Comment: @Rocket Seeing as it's the main clue as to the purpose of a variable, yes it does. Perhaps not for this question seeing as the code sample was very short, but I intended the comment as general advice to a new user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var contapara=1;
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
var l = document.getElementById(contapara).innerHTML.replace(regex, "");
alert(l);
```

Regex is our friend :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var contapara = 3;
var l = $.trim($('#'+contapara).text());
alert(l); // Little birds
```

Instead of using `document.getElementById`, I'm using jQuery to get the element.  I'm also using `.text()` (`innerText` or `textContent`) instead of `.html()` (`innerHTML`).

Answer (score 2):

Using Plain javascript (Tested in chrome, IE, FF and opera)

```
var contapara=3;
var n = document.getElementById(contapara).childNodes;
for(i=0;i<n.length;i++)
{
    if(n[i].nodeType==3 && n[i].nodeValue!=' ') alert(n[i].nodeValue);
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/YJbHe/3/)